# How to get Select option dropdown text value using reactive form in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access the text as a value. Currently I'm able to retrieve the value but not the text.

```
<select id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control">
  <option value="Not Selected" [disabled]="true" [selected]="true">Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let fName of clientFileData.worksheets[0].columns" value={{fName.index}}>{{fName.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Using `this.firstName.value` I'm able to get the value which is `fName.index` but I also want to access the `fName.name`. How can I retrive that value eqivalent of `$("#firstName:selected").text();` in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a simple solution although it only works if the option list doesn't contains comma which works in my case.

```
<select id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control">
  <option value="Not Selected" [disabled]="true" [selected]="true">Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let fName of clientFileData.worksheets[0].columns" value={{fName.index}},{{fName.name}}>{{fName.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This will return index with name in a string. Eg: `"1,John Doe"`.

Then we can manipulate the comma separated string using split method.

```
console.log('Index: ' + this.firstName.value.split(',')[0]);
console.log('Name: ' + this.firstName.value.split(',')[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this code and it worked for me try this in html use this code on select

```
<select id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" (change)="getName($event)"
 class="form-control">
```

and in ts file

```
getName(e:Event){
   const value:number =  parseInt((<HTMLSelectElement>event.srcElement).value);
   console.log((<HTMLSelectElement>event.srcElement.options[selectedIndex]text))
  }
```

Let me know if you it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

why don't you bind the value with `fName` instead of {{fName.index}}? doing so will give you the whole object and then you can find the name property inside of it. However, in `Angular` you can use `@ViewChild` to achieve similar to `$("#firstName:selected").text();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a simple way but you could have a `(change)` event in which you use the `fName.index` to iterate through your `clientFileData` array and find the equivalent name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You need to go through the list of options you're rendering, find selected one by id and get the text from it. This is just the way HTML select works: `I only give you id of the selected item, so, if you want its text then go figure it out yourself`, be it jquery or plain javascript using selected index property or something else. BTW, I'm sure that jquery does something similar under the hood.

It is also possible to make angular binding work with the whole objects as a model rather than just their ids. This way you will be able to just get your text directly from the model that select is bound to. However, this will require you to provide custom value accessor and probably a bit of some other stuff. It may sound scary at first but it should not be very complicated.